# How to plot a differentiable function using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am tryinig to plot the differential function y' = 3t-sqrt(y), but my code doesn't produce any graph output. Can someone point out my mistake please?

```
import sympy.plotting as sym_plot

def func(y, t):
    return 3*t - np.sqrt(y)

# time points
t = np.linspace(0,5)

# initial condition
y0 = 3

# solve ODE
y = odeint(func,y0,t)

plt.plot(t,y)
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('y(t)')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you printed out the y's to see what you are plotting?

Comment: your code works fine on my end: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSGfI.png

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any output at all? And did you give func arguments here?

```
y = odeint(func,y0,t)
```

Also, you are missing some important imports for your code in the question. Maybe adding them to the code snippet will help you get a better answer.

Edit: After adding the imports and trying the code out myself, a graph is outputted. This doesn't seem like a problem with your code.